# Connection Timed out on SSH Server

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I am using the internet server of university and trying to log in to my account on system from my laptop, using ssh -X username@server. It says connection timed out. when i tried from another system i was able to log in. i use system for pretty basic work and dont know much about the internal coding and all... From some of he pages online i think the problem is firewall or something similar. 
I have checked the status for open ssh server which is shown as active. Kindly guide me through how to solve this problem.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04. and connecting from with in university. and using the address provided by the officilas... the same address works if i am doing it through another system that has the same version of ubuntu.

Comment: i havent done anything to have firewall. "ufw" shows an active status, if thats related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is with your ssh configuration, nothing to do with firewall for outgoing SSH session. See your /etc/ssh/ssh_config file and make sure you enable both the following:

```
ForwardX11 yes
ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

For some situation, you might have to turn off trusted mode for things to work (all depends on the SSH setup in your university.

```
ForwardX11Trusted no
```

Hope this helps.

(Edited)

In cases where you can't edit the configuration in /etc/ssh/ssh_config, copy the file to your home directory and modify it there.

```
mkdir $HOME/.ssh
cp /etc/ssh/ssh_config $HOME/.ssh/config
```

Modify `~/.ssh/config` to enable X11 forwarding.

Comment: Thank you for your help. i think that is actually the problem, "ForwardX11 no" i found this in the file you mentioned, but it is not allowing for the editing. what i mean is i cant save it after editting. can you kindly guide me about that...

Comment: See if you can make a copy of the configuration file to your home directory as `my.config` make the modification there and then launch it with `ssh -X -F my.config username@server`

Comment: I have updated the answer on how to have a user specific configuration.

Comment: I tried the both methods. "~/.ssh/config" says permission denied and ssh -X -F my.config username@server is still connection timed out. Thank you for your time and kind help. i think i might be doing it the wrong way.

Comment: Perhaps you can include `-vvv` when you try to make the ssh connection. Add the debug output to your question. I'm curious to see what other things causing the timeout.

Comment: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/ubuntu/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "10.9.41.100" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.9.41.100 [10.9.41.100] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 10.9.41.100 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 10.9.41.100 port 22: Connection timed out

Comment: .ssh folder was present in home directory instead of /etc/ssh/ssh.config, editing there solved the problem. Thank you for your kind help.

Answer (score 1):

Install ufw It will handle the firewall.

This guide will help you go through the basics of firewalls.

https://www.linode.com/docs/security/firewalls/configure-firewall-with-ufw/

Run these commands on the ssh-server machine

```
sudo apt-get install ufw
sudo ufw allow ssh
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw status
```

These will get you through.

Let me know what happened.

Comment: ufw is already working. and status is also active.

Comment: what does the status show?

when you press sudo ufw status

is it something like 22/tcp ALLOW ANYWHERE

Comment: That it is active.

Comment: I can understand it's active but does it say that port 22 is allowed when you ask for the status?

Comment: yes it does. port 22 allowed anywhere.

Comment: now it should allow you if you try to ssh into the host machine.